# Java Scrolling Bar disappears when using BorderLayout NORTH

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, border-layout, jscrollbar

Problem and Code Summary:
This will make sense if you run the code below. I'm using a `JScrollPane` and its scroll bar is disappearing when it is placed in a `JPanel` with a `BorderLayout` (NORTH). When the `JPanel` has a `BorderLayout` (CENTER), it works fine (with the scroll bar showing up). If you try to remove many of the components with the remove buttons, it gets annoying because the `JScrollPane` (with all of its components) clumps up in the middle of the `JPanel` it's in, when you want it to stay at the top. I tried to prevent this by obviously changing the `BorderLayout` of the `JPanel` from CENTER TO NORTH, but that just takes out the scroll bar completely. In the following code, the Main.placement (line 28) (change it to CENTER/NORTH to mess with it) controls the type of layout being used and line 171 shows how it is implemented. I just want to align the `JSCrollPane` at the top with the scroll bar showing up when it is neccessary.
Code Summary:

```
package main;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class Main{
    public static final String placement = BorderLayout.CENTER;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new TimeChart(true);
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class TimeChart extends JFrame {
    private boolean admin;

    private TimeTable timeTable;
    private static final JLabel title;
    private final JLabel volLabel;

    static {
        title = new JLabel("Time Chart ");
    }

    private class TimeTable extends JPanel {

        private JScrollPane scrollPane;
        private JPanel table;

        public final ArrayList<SessionRow> sessionRows;

        private final JButton addButton;

        private final JButton applyButton;

        private static final double weight_sessnum = 0.2;
        private static final double weight_signinout = 1.0;
        private static final double weight_time = 0.3;
        private static final double weight_delete = 0.0;

        public class SessionRow {
            private final SessionRow thisSessionRow; // for inner classes
            private JTextField sessionnum, signinField, signoutField, total;

            private JButton removeButton;

            private SessionRow(int y) {
                thisSessionRow = this;

                String signinstring = "*signin time*";

                String signoutstring = "*signout time*";

                sessionnum = new JTextField("Session " + y + ": ");
                sessionnum.setEditable(false);

                signinField = new JTextField(signinstring);
                signinField.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                        signinField.selectAll();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                    }
                });
                signinField.setEditable(admin);

                signoutField = new JTextField(signoutstring);
                signoutField.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                        signoutField.selectAll();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                    }
                });
                signoutField.setEditable(admin);

                String totalstring = null;
                try {
                    totalstring = "*session total*";
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    totalstring = " -- ";
                }
                total = new JTextField(totalstring);
                total.setEditable(false);

                removeButton = new JButton("Remove");
                removeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        thisSessionRow.remove();
                        sessionRows.remove(thisSessionRow);
                        revalidate();
                        repaint();

                    }
                });
            }
            public void remove() {
                table.remove(this.sessionnum);
                table.remove(this.signinField);
                table.remove(this.signoutField);
                table.remove(this.total);
                table.remove(this.removeButton);
            }

        }

        public TimeTable() {
            super();

            table = new JPanel();
            scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

            applyButton = new JButton("<html><div style=\"text-align: center;\">Apply<br>Changes</html>");
            applyButton.setMargin(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
            applyButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    applyAllChanges();
                }
            });
            applyButton.setEnabled(false);

            addButton = new JButton("Add");
            addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    sessionRows.add(new SessionRow(sessionRows.size() + 1));
                    setupAll();
                    revalidate();
                    repaint();
                    if (!applyButton.isEnabled())
                        applyButton.setEnabled(true);
                }
            });

            sessionRows = new ArrayList<SessionRow>();
            setupSessionRows();

            setupAll();

            this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            this.add(scrollPane, Main.placement); //PAY ATTENTION HERE

            JScrollBar bar = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
            bar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 0));
            bar.setUnitIncrement(10);
            InputMap im = bar.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);

            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("down"), "positiveUnitIncrement");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("up"), "negativeUnitIncrement");

            scrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
            this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.green));

        }

        public void setupSessionRows() {
            sessionRows.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                sessionRows.add(new SessionRow(i + 1));
            }
            System.gc();
        }

        public void setupAll() {
            table.removeAll();

            table.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            c.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 2);

            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 0;
            initColumnHeader(c);

            for (int y = 0; y < sessionRows.size(); y++) {
                c.gridy++;
                initSessRow(sessionRows.get(y), c);
            }

            c.gridy++;

            if (admin) {
                initNewButtonRow(c);
                c.gridy++;
            }

            initTotalHeader(c);

        }

        public void initSessRow(SessionRow row, GridBagConstraints c) {

            c.weightx = weight_sessnum;
            c.gridx = 0;
            table.add(row.sessionnum, c);

            c.weightx = weight_signinout;
            c.gridx = 1;
            table.add(row.signinField, c);

            c.weightx = weight_signinout;
            c.gridx = 2;
            table.add(row.signoutField, c);

            c.weightx = weight_time;
            c.gridx = 3;
            table.add(row.total, c);

            if (admin) {
                c.weightx = weight_delete;
                c.gridx = 4;
                table.add(row.removeButton, c);
            }

        }

        public void initTotalHeader(GridBagConstraints c) {
            c.weightx = weight_sessnum;
            c.gridx = 0;
            JTextField totalLabel = new JTextField("Total: ");
            totalLabel.setEditable(false);
            table.add(totalLabel, c);

            c.weightx = weight_signinout;
            c.gridx = 1;
            JTextField blank1 = new JTextField();
            blank1.setEditable(false);
            table.add(blank1, c);

            c.weightx = weight_signinout;
            c.gridx = 2;
            JTextField blank2 = new JTextField();
            blank2.setEditable(false);
            table.add(blank2, c);

            c.weightx = weight_time;
            c.gridx = 3;
            JTextField totaltime = new JTextField("*TOTAL*");
            totaltime.setEditable(false);
            table.add(totaltime, c);

            if (admin) {
                c.weightx = weight_delete;
                c.gridx = 4;
                table.add(applyButton, c);
            }

        }

        public void initNewButtonRow(GridBagConstraints c) {
            c.weightx = weight_sessnum;
            c.gridx = 0;
            table.add(addButton, c);

            c.weightx = weight_signinout;
            c.gridx = 1;
            JTextField blank1 = new JTextField();
            blank1.setEditable(false);
            table.add(blank1, c);

            c.weightx = weight_signinout;
            c.gridx = 2;
            JTextField blank2 = new JTextField();
            blank2.setEditable(false);
            table.add(blank2, c);

            c.weightx = weight_time;
            c.gridx = 3;
            JTextField blank3 = new JTextField();
            blank3.setEditable(false);
            table.add(blank3, c);

            if (admin) {
                c.weightx = weight_delete;
                c.gridx = 4;
                JTextField blank4 = new JTextField();
                blank4.setEditable(false);
                table.add(blank4, c);
            }

        }

        public void initColumnHeader(GridBagConstraints c) {

            c.weightx = weight_sessnum;
            c.gridx = 0;
            JTextField sessnum = new JTextField("Session #");
            sessnum.setEditable(false);
            table.add(sessnum, c);

            c.weightx = weight_signinout;
            c.gridx = 1;
            JTextField signintime = new JTextField("Sign in Time");
            signintime.setEditable(false);
            table.add(signintime, c);

            c.weightx = weight_signinout;
            c.gridx = 2;
            JTextField signouttime = new JTextField("Sign out Time");
            signouttime.setEditable(false);
            table.add(signouttime, c);

            c.weightx = weight_time;
            c.gridx = 3;
            JTextField time = new JTextField("Time");
            time.setEditable(false);
            table.add(time, c);

            if (admin) {
                c.weightx = weight_delete;
                c.gridx = 4;
                JTextField delete = new JTextField("Delete");
                delete.setEditable(false);
                table.add(delete, c);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void revalidate() {
            if (sessionRows != null) {

                int i = 1;
                for (SessionRow sr : sessionRows) {
                    sr.sessionnum.setText("Session " + i);
                    i++;
                }
            }
            super.revalidate();
        }

    }

    public TimeChart(boolean admin) {
        super();

        this.admin = admin;

        volLabel = new JLabel("Billy");

        timeTable = new TimeTable();

        this.setSize(900, 900);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        initFrame();

        this.setVisible(true);
        scrollDown();
    }

    public void initFrame() {
        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        c.weightx = 1.0;
        c.weighty = 0.0;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        this.add(title, c);

        c.weightx = 1.0;
        c.weighty = 0.0;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        this.add(volLabel, c);

        c.weightx = 1.0;
        c.weighty = 1.0;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        this.add(timeTable, c);

    }

    public void scrollDown() {
        JScrollBar bar = timeTable.scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
        bar.setValue(bar.getMaximum());
    }

    public void applyAllChanges() {
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance, I really appreciate it.

Comment: The component in the north position is been maintained at it's preferredSize, so the `JScrollPane` is never been decreased in size to the point where it needs scroll bars. Personally, I'd think a `JTable` would be simpler to setup, but that's just me

Comment: @MadProgrammer How can the table(JPanel) inside the JScrollPane be at its preferredSize if it doesn't show up completely? Not all of it is visible. And i can't use JTable because our teacher has not allowed us to.

Comment: It is been all displayed, your initial window size is to small, try using `pack` on the frame instead of `setSize`, but do it just before you call `setVisible` (the `JScrollPane` is been allowed to overflow the visible bounds of the window)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I did this.pack(); then this.setVisible(); and the frame got much longer to match the preferredSize of the table, but when I resized the JFrame smaller, the JScrollBar still didn't show up. Instead it just started cutting the other components in the table out completely.

Comment: *"so the JScrollPane is never been decreased in size to the point where it needs scroll bars"* - which is why it never shows scroll bars...This might sound weird, but that would the expectations of `BorderLayout`

Comment: @MadProgrammer Is there a layout or any fix that allows the entire JScrollPane to fit inside the JPanel (decrease to the size of the JPanel) yet maintain a position on the TOP/NORTH if the JScrollPane is too small?

Comment: `GridBagLayout` can do, if you configure it right

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you.

Comment: Was this ever figured out? I'm having pretty close to the same problem using BorderLayout. If you achieved it with BorderLayout or GridBagLayout, can you display your answer?

Comment: @DarkHark i am pretty sure I switched to a gridbaglayout, they almost never have any problems.

Comment: @akarshkumar0101 Thanks. Unfortunately I can't really do that because I'm trying to make my panels dynamic. I'm trying out the BoxLayout now.